# Override hosts variable of Ansible playbook without command line

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

Have 2 hosts my_host1, my_host2
This code work for my_host1, I also need run it for my_host2
Can be overridden hosts value on ansible main.yml task without changing string "hosts: my_host1" in init playbook.yml?
Command line --extra-vars is not the solution for me.

Thank you

```
---

#init playbook.yml
- name: run role test
  hosts: my_host1
  roles:
   - role: test_1

---

#main.yml in role test_1

   - name: Run tasks from example.yml
     block:
       - include_tasks: example.yml


---
# example.yml

   - debug:
       msg: "This is example task"
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail why command line options are no option for you? As well why it is not possible to write an inventory?

Comment: You might be interested in background information about [Add host during runtime execution w/o starting new play](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71983263/6771046).

Answer (score 0):

`--extra-vars` would not work anyway, since the hosts definition is not a variable.

Usually you add the hosts where you want to run a playbook, if not defined explicitly in the playbook, via the `--limit` argument.

```yaml
# playbook.yml
- name: run role test
  hosts: all
```

Then you execute:

```bash
ansible-playbook playbook.yaml --limit my_host1,myhost2
```

Or you provide a group defined in the inventory

```ini
[my_hosts]
my_host1
my_host2
```

call:

```bash
ansible-playbook playbook.yaml --limit my_hosts
```

Comment: I need do it without command line

Comment: Then you need to either define it in the playbook or in the inventory. These are the only options.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply write an inventory file with a [computer] block for instance, and then set your hosts: computer.

Your playbook will be applied on every hosts within your inventory.
That's the base of Ansible purpose.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html

Comment: Thank you. it is not possible.